# How do I "link" a web2py database?

Tags: python, database, web2py

I am trying to make a database for stock data in web2py like, Company A holds data for equity in 2010, 2011, 2012... and Company B holds data for equity in 2010, 2011, 2012...
This is what I come up with.

```
db.define_table(
    'company',
    Field('name'),
    format = '%(name)s')

db.define_table(
    'years',
    Field('fiscal_year'),
    format = '%(fiscal_year)s')

db.define_table(
    'stock_data',
    Field('company_id', db.company),
    Field('years_id', db.years),
    Field('equity', 'integer'),
    format = '%(equity)s %(years_id)s -> %(company_id)s')

db.company.name.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'company.name')
db.years.fiscal_year.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'years.fiscal_year')
```

The problem is that I can repeat the same year for a company many times with different values.
How can I "link" a year to a company and the equity value for that year.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `years` table? Can't you put the year directly in the `stock_data` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want *combinations* of `company_id` and `years_id` to be unique, you can do something like:

```
db.define_table(
    'stock_data',
    Field('company_id', db.company),
    Field('years_id', db.years),
    Field('equity', 'integer'),
    format = '%(equity)s %(years_id)s -> %(company_id)s')

matching_company_id = db.stock_data.company_id == request.vars.company_id
unique_company_year = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(matching_company_id), 'stock_data.years_id')
db.stock_data.years_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'years.id', db.years._format,
                                           _and=unique_company_year)
```

In the above, `unique_company_year` ensures that the submitted value of `years_id` is unique among the set of records whose `company_id` matches the submitted `company_id` (this guarantees that the `company_id`/`years_id` pair is unique while allowing non-unique values on either field alone). This `IS_NOT_IN_DB` validator is then passed as the `_and` argument to the standard `IS_IN_DB` validator for the field.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what if i want to change the value or to add another field.

Comment: If you want to change a value via an update form, it should still work. If you add another field and therefore need trios of values to be unique, the same logic applies -- set an `IS_NOT_IN_DB` validator on one field, defining the relevant set as those that match the submitted values on the other two fields.